# About the domain of the adjoint of the unbounded multiplication oeprator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $Af(x)=xf(x)$ is defined on $D(A)=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):xf\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$, then $A$ is known to be self-adjoint and so $D(A^*)=D(A)$. The proof is available is many textbooks. One proof may be found in the classical textbook by Akhiezer-Glazman (theory of linear oeprators in Hilbert space). The "big" problem is on Page 104: Indeed, they say that "if we restrict $A$ to a smaller domain, i.e. to $D'\subset D(A)$ and call this restriction $A'$, then similar arguments show that $A'^*=A$ and so $A=\overline{A'}$!!!".

I am not sure at all about this last statement. Indeed, if $A'$ is a (proper) closed restriction of $A$, then according to the last statement: $A=A'$ which is impossible!

Any explanation is most welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Math

Comment: Nobody said that $A'$ is self-adjoint. It is only symmetric, which means that $A'\subset (A')^\star$. There is no contradiction with $(A')^\star=A$.

Comment: The contradiction is when $A'$ is closed. Indeed, $(A')^*=A$ yields $A'=(A')^{**}=\overline{A'}=A$.

Comment: I don't get what they are saying [there](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UirEAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=operation%20of%20multiplication&f=false). What if $A$ is multiplication on functions defined on the line and $A'$ is the restriction to functions with support on $(0,1)$? Perhaps there is some unstated (or elsewhere stated) assumption.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. Your $A'$ is unclosed. It may not be a counterexample. I am pretty sure their argument is not correct. I think if $A'$ is defined on a core, then their remark is fine.